# Why ajax upload file doesn't need enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, file-upload

I have a form which use to I send using Ajax with jQuery. And like you can see in the title the question is: Why ajax upload file doesn't need `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form tag?

The example something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
$("form1").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'formprocessing.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (returndata) {
      alert(returndata);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
</script>
</head>
    <form id="form1">
        <input name="image" type="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're posting the form content with ajax, so the attributes on the `<form>` tag are irrelevant. Your own code is basically doing the work that the browser would do if the form were posted implicitly by the browser.